# Can this linear transformation be onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

(Exercise from Lay, Lay, McDonald.) Consider an invertible linear transformation $f:R^n\to R^n$ such that $f(u)=f(v)$ for a pair of distinct vectors $u,v$. Can it map $R^n$ onto $R^n$?

I suppose the answer is no.  My reasoning is that since $f(u)=f(v)$, it is not one-to-one. But being one-to-one is the same is being onto for finite-dimensional vector spaces. Am I right?

Comment: But if it's invertible,  it must be $1-1$.

Comment: F is invertible so it must be one to one but even if not then, F(u)=f(v) implies that ker(f)!={0}, now from dimension theorem for vector spaces dimker(f)+dim im(f)=n I.e dim imf < n and f isn't onto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invertibility is equivalent to injectivity is equivalent to trivial kernel.

You can't have $f(u)=f(v)$ for distinct $u,v$ **and** invertibility.

The exercise makes no sense.